# Complex derivative of absolute value?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function.

I wonder what
$$\partial_z \frac{1}{\vert f(z) \vert} \text{ and }\partial_{\bar z} \frac{1}{\vert f(z) \vert} $$
are?

I would guess that since
$$ |f(z)|=\sqrt{f(z) \overline{f(z)}}$$

we have $$\partial_z |f(z)| = \frac{f'(z)\overline{f(z)}}{2\vert f(z)\vert^2}$$

and $$ \partial_{\bar z} |f(z)| = \frac{\overline{f'(z)}f(z)}{2\vert f(z) \vert^2}.$$

Thus, by some chain rule, perhaps

$$\partial_z |f(z)|^{-1} = -\frac{f'(z)\overline{f(z)}}{2\vert f(z)\vert^4}$$
and
$$ \partial_{\bar z} |f(z)|^{-1} = -\frac{\overline{f'(z)}f(z)}{2\vert f(z) \vert^4}.$$

Comment: You are missing $1/2$ and your exponent in the denominator is wrong.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see the missing $1/2$. Why is the exponent wrong, though?

Comment: exponent should be $3$ since the derivative of $\sqrt u$ is $1/(2\sqrt u)$, so $\partial_z |f(z)| = \frac{f'(z)\overline{f(z)}}{2\sqrt {\vert f(z)\vert^2}}$; it is easy to double check with $f(z)=z^2$ since then $|f(z)|=z \bar z$ so $\partial_z |f(z)|=\bar z=\frac{2z \overline {z^2}}{2|f(z)|}$